# Return the generic class instance with anonymous type based on Newexpression

Tags: c#, generics, lambda, anonymous-types

I have generic class "MSAccessQueryBuilder" with the following method

```
public I_QueryBuilder<T> Select(Expression<Func<T, object>> fieldNames)
    {
        NewExpression nEx = (NewExpression)fieldNames.Body;
        MsAccessQueryBuilder<"Anonymous Type Of Expression"> x = new MsAccessQueryBuilder<"Anonymous Type Of Expression">();

    }
```

within the method I need to create the instance of the "MSAccessQueryBuilder" with a generic type which anonymously created in lambda expression.

The method will be called like below

```
x.Select(s=> new {p1 = s.user_id,p2 = s.user_name})
```

Tried 8 hours of my own with no luck.

is this possible to get the anonymous type from NewExpression or LambdaExpression and create the instance of generic class of that anonymous type

Please help

Thank you

Comment: Could you give us some information on what is the actual behaviour? Compiler error or runtime Error? Or is it just not working as expected?

Comment: Actually i don't know how to create the generic class with anonymous type and how to get the type from variable "nEx"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have to change the method signature  as Func delegate return type as generic instead of object solved the problem

```
public I_QueryBuilder<TResult> Select(Expression<Func<T, TResult>> fieldNames)
{

    return new MsAccessQueryBuilder<TResult>();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this.

```
var genericType = typeof(MsAccessQueryBuilder<>);
var specificType = genericType.MakeGenericType(typeof(nEx));
var x = Activator.CreateInstance(specificType);
```

Comment: Hi, i need to create the instance of the generic class based on the anonymous object passed by lambda expression (where the body of the lambdaexpression is always a type of "newexpression") not by the expression itself